# How to achieve a similar behavior to display: inline with flex items when text breaks?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a piece of text (let's call it the "title"), and a "badge" on the right. I want the badge to stick to the end of the title when the title breaks.

As in the following snippet, I could achieve this by setting the `display` of both the title and badge elements to either `inline` or `inline-block`:

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}

.small-container {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.title {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.badge {
  display: inline;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p style="color: gray">In a normal state:<p>
<div class="container">
  <span class="title">This is the title of the product</span>
  <span class="badge">3.4 rating</span>
</div>

<p style="color: gray; margin-top: 30px">Now, when the container is not wide enough, the text breaks and the badge stays at the end of it, exactly what we want:<p>
<div class="container small-container">
  <span class="title">This is the title of the product</span>
  <span class="badge">3.4 rating</span>
</div>
```

With flexbox, on the other hand, the following snippet is what I've done, but the badge, in this case, doesn't stick to the end of the title when the title breaks, it instead creates a new line by itself:

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.small-container {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.title {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.badge {
  display: inline;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p style="color: gray">In a normal state:<p>
<div class="container">
  <span class="title">This is the title of the product</span>
  <span class="badge">3.4 rating</span>
</div>

<p style="color: gray; margin-top: 30px">Now, when the container is not wide enough, the text breaks, BUT the badge goes to new line by itself:<p>
<div class="container small-container">
  <span class="title">This is the title of the product</span>
  <span class="badge">3.4 rating</span>
</div>
```

How do I achieve a similar result to my first snippet when I have a flex container?

Comment: You can not. This is how display flex works:(

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Oh okay. But what do people commonly do in these cases then? Is what I had done initially (using `display: inline`) a reasonable approach to this? Is it the only approach?

Comment: yes it's the only approach

Comment: if this is what you need, it is the reasonable approach. CSS is only about styling :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ok then, thanks.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it make sense to treat the whole thing as one flex-item? That way they will remain together as if inline.

```
<span class="title">This is the title of the product<span class="badge">3.4 rating</span></span>
```

Comment: Then that would be 2 `inline` elements, just like what I had in my first snippet, so it's not using flexbox. I just wanted to know if this is possible with flexbox. I was just told it's apparently not (in the comments). Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Arad, thanks for the clarification. I think what I was trying to suggest was that even though there are 2 `inline` elements in my refactor, it is only 1 inline element with regards to the flex container (the `title` is a flex-item, not the `badge`). This way the flex keeps the span together on wrap.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lz24ox6g/